How to prevent primary key reading back after DbContext.Add()
"EntityFrameworkCore in action" by Jon P Smith talks:

The second SQL command produced by EF Core reads back the primary key of the row that was created by the database server. This command ensures that the original ExampleEntity instance is updated with the primary key so that the in-memory version of the entity is the same as the version in the database. Reading back the primary key is important, as you might update the entity later, and the update will need the primary key.

That's really happens (logs of EFC queries in my app):
INSERT INTO `person` (`name`)
VALUES ('john');
SELECT `id`
FROM `person`
WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();

But actually my app doesn't need added entity after DbContext.Add(), hence app shouldn't read primary key back.
using var context = MyDbContext();
context.Add(new Person
{
    Name = 'john'
});
GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced); // I tried garbage collecting, but, obviously, it didn't help
context.SaveChanges();
// created earlier entity is not used further, so it's value of primary key doesn't matter

The workaround I've found is to change id type from int to int? but it's awkward, although works (there's no key selecting back after Add()).
Well, the only thing I want to know: some way to avoid selecting primary key id column back exits?

"Reading back the primary key is important, as you might update the entity later, and the update will need the primary key." This is the way EF was designed. U can use raw SQL to add your entity if you don't want to get back the inserted item id.

Taking a step back... Why do you need to modify this internal Entity Framework behavior?  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

I am not 100% certain, but can you not just disable tracking to prevent this? QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

@DA uh. and i can't change it in a simple way?

@David because there's only insert privilegy on that user

@JulianHüppauff nope

Please use [entity-framework-core] tag together with [ef-core-xx] where xx is the version you use. Also, please indicate which source you quote right at the beginning.

Duplicate (but w/o good answers) How to avoid inserted entity to be selected after insert in EF Core?.
